# smartface update and clear buttons in iOS widget disappeared

Tags: smartface.io

After pressing the Clear button, both Clear and Update buttons disappeared.

Now there is only Scan button and it doesn't work.

After pressing Scan, application opens and closes.

Restarting iPhone didn't work :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On some devices we faced this issue and released an update a few days ago. Could you check latest version on the app store?